# Creating a multiindexed `Series` with a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, series

In my mind, what I'm trying to do ought to be straightforward, as straightforward as passing it into the constructor, but in reality it's not. I have a dictionary like below.

```
d = {"russell": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
    "cantor": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
    "godel": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)}}
```

I would like to do something like `pandas.Series(d)` and get a `Series` instance like below.

```
russell  score  0.87391482
         ping   23
cantor   score  0.77821932
         ping   16
godel    score  0.53372128
         ping   35
```

But what I actually get is below.

```
cantor     {'ping': 44, 'score': 0.007408727109865398}
godel        {'ping': 41, 'score': 0.9338940910283948}
russell       {'ping': 74, 'score': 0.733817307366666}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {"russell": {"score": np.random.rand(), "ping": np.random.randint(10, 100)},
    "cantor": {"score": np.random.rand(), "ping": np.random.randint(10, 100)},
    "godel": {"score": np.random.rand(), "ping": np.random.randint(10, 100)}}

print (pd.DataFrame(d).unstack())  

cantor   ping     33.000000
         score     0.240253
godel    ping     64.000000
         score     0.435040
russell  ping     41.000000
         score     0.171810
dtype: float64
```

Also if need swap levels in `MultiIndex` use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame(d).stack())    
ping   cantor     64.000000
       godel      40.000000
       russell    66.000000
score  cantor      0.265771
       godel       0.283725
       russell     0.085856
dtype: float64
```