# Creating a multiindexed `DataFrame` with a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, series

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261031/creating-a-multiindexed-series-with-a-nested-dictionary/40261065#40261065). This time I want to go one step further. Given a dictionary like:

```
dd = {0: {"russell": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "cantor": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "godel": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)}},

      1: {"russell": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "cantor": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "godel": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)}}}
```

or a list like:

```
ll = [{"russell": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "cantor": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "godel": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)}},

      {"russell": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "cantor": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)},
          "godel": {"score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)}}]
```

I would like to construct a `DataFrame` like:

```
                          russell                            godel                        cantor
                    score    ping                    score    ping                 score    ping
0     0.17473916938994682      40       0.3443303845926545      47   0.43576522521017247      42
1      0.7341005512329682      22      0.14682222267827938      81    0.5662517436162526      59
```

where as we can see the column index is a `MultiIndex`. Is there a way of achieving that? If I try `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient="index")` or `pandas.DataFrame(ll)` then I get:

```
                                      russell                                       godel                                      cantor
0  {'score': 0.17473916938994682, 'ping': 40}   {'score': 0.3443303845926545, 'ping': 47}  {'score': 0.43576522521017247, 'ping': 42}
1   {'score': 0.7341005512329682, 'ping': 22}  {'score': 0.14682222267827938, 'ping': 81}   {'score': 0.5662517436162526, 'ping': 59}
```

which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is more complicated, but [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html) with [`transpose`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.transpose.html), [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.to_frame.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) can help:

```
df = pd.Panel(dd).transpose(2,0,1).to_frame().unstack()
print (df)
      cantor           godel           russell          
minor   ping     score  ping     score    ping     score
major                                                   
0       69.0  0.050641  51.0  0.765994    20.0  0.935196
1       91.0  0.398624  33.0  0.408681    75.0  0.464876
```

Comment: you have personally helped me so much with Pandas. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

this would also work. note that your nested dict is not really nested for easy translation.

```
 pd.concat({key:pd.DataFrame(dd[key]) for key in dd.keys()}).unstack()
Out[104]: 
  cantor           godel           russell          
    ping     score  ping     score    ping     score
0   73.0  0.463084  94.0  0.954662    76.0  0.732291
1   28.0  0.778905  81.0  0.984285    36.0  0.094173
```

in short creating a multi index df with concat is super easy. you just need a dictionary of dataframes